# How to unlink my Nintendo ID from the 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

My 3DS has some games downloaded. I want to make it stop using my current Nintendo ID when entering the store. I see two ways to do so:

- **Factory reset**: This is absurd.
- **Delete the Nintendo ID, and destroy any games purchased by it**: Are you kidding me?

What am I supposed to do? I just want to unlink my Nintendo ID from this device without losing anything.

Comment: Pretty sure that it is impossible.

Comment: @AshleyNunn: Ok, so if I decide to *delete* the Nintendo ID and destroy all my purchases, can I at least use an existing Nintendo ID from a different device?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 3):

Call Nintendo. They're pretty good with offering solutions you may not have thought of, even if it involves sending it in. They have superb customer service, too

1 (800) 255-3700

Comment: how does this even help? call nintendo means absolutely nothing

Comment: I've seen reports that this works. I quote from a site I probably shouldn't link to: "I unlinked my 3DS by calling Nintendo directly. They ask you a few questions (things you purchased, ect.) to make sure it's your account and then they send a report to the admins. They'll unlink it within a few days, sometimes immediately."

Comment: It helps because calling Nintendo is usually the best way to take care of things like this. they can give you options, such as shipping it in and having the ID removed and switched to another 3DS, or if you want, I think they can do it over the phone

Comment: Yeah, this worked for me today. I wish they had an automated solution, but this wasn't too painful. He asked a few questions about the account (what games had been played, last four digits of the associated credit card, etc), and that was that.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that you can use a nintendo id from another device, i did this with my 3ds because i had two accounts including my wii u because at the time i had forgotten the first one that i set up.

I ended up doing a factory reset on my 3ds and logging in with my newer wii u login which had the higher balance.

I hope this helps that at least you have an option, unfortunately you cant keep your games from the other account.

Answer (score 0):

Call nintendo, I did. My 3ds broke and was so old a beat up it made no sense to try anD get it fixed after being run over by a car. I bought a new one and all they need is the serial number of both systems, verfication questions, and a list of what you've purchased digitally.

Answer (score -2):

I've called Nintendo when my 3ds screen broke and got a new system. They linked my new serial number to my Nintendo network id then i was able to login on new system and redownloaded all my stuff from purchase history to the new system without any issues man.

Comment: Who's the issues man?